# Python - Tkinter & while loop at the same time

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, while-loop

I'm a python beginner. I want to know if there is a way to run a loop at the same time as I am running a tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x280")
root.title("Test")
Window=Frame(root,relief="raise", bg="#282d38")
Window.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()

while True:
    print("hi")
```

I want a loop running while my window is running.

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response! :) I'm quite new to this. How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: I convert it to answer, so now you can :)

Comment: some things you can do with `root.after()` instead of `while` loop or threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Threading is what you need. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Example:

```
import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t show integration of threads with tkinter.